# Android NotificationListenerService android:exported value

Tags: android, android-service, notificationlistenerservice, androidexported

Here is example of declaration notification listener service

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.notifications.NotificationListenerService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
    android:stopWithTask="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Is it means if android:exported="true" and `BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission is granted by user explicitly, then other app can use this service without asking user permission one more time? So what is security concern of setting exported to true for this particular service?